# How to Record Internal Audio in a Flutter App on Android?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, audio-recording, call-recording

I am working on a Flutter app that requires the ability to record internal audio, such as audio playing from other apps or the device's system sounds, on Android devices. I have researched the topic, but I'm finding it challenging to figure out a reliable way to achieve this without resorting to risky practices like rooting the device.

Is there a non-root solution or a safe method to record internal audio in a Flutter app on Android? I'm aware of the privacy and security concerns surrounding this functionality, and I want to ensure that my app complies with all guidelines and respects users' privacy.

If recording internal audio is not possible in Flutter alone, are there any recommended workarounds or external libraries that I can use in conjunction with Flutter to achieve this functionality?

I would appreciate any insights, code examples, or pointers to relevant resources that can help me implement internal audio recording in my Flutter app while adhering to best practices and ensuring a smooth user experience.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of Android devices that come with built-in call recording features. These features are typically enabled by default, and they don't require users to grant any special permissions. This suggests that Google is okay with apps that record audio from calls (like [Google apps and Web activity](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6030020?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid)), but they may be less okay with apps that record audio from other sources.

I did not find that "Recording global Audio in Android is now against Google's policy due to privacy concerns", but it sure is harder.

See [Google’s crackdown on third-party Android call recorders may finally be complete](https://www.theverge.com/2022/4/21/23036078/google-android-call-recording-apps-accessibility-loopholes-play-store-rules) by [Mitchell Clark](https://www.theverge.com/authors/mitchell-clark):

> Google is changing its Play Store policy to clamp down on a workaround that call recording apps were using, potentially closing the final loophole that allowed these apps to exist (via [NLL-Apps on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/u81i7b/google_will_kill_call_recording_apps_once_and_for/)). On May 11th, [a rule clarifying](https://web.archive.org/web/20220408055128/https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11899428#accessibility_preview) that “the Accessibility API is not designed and cannot be requested for remote call audio recording” will go into effect, making it so that apps won’t be able to record audio from a call.

And see [Google is banning third-party call recording apps from the Play Store](https://www.engadget.com/google-is-banning-third-party-call-recording-apps-from-the-play-store-093201443.html) from [Steve Dent](https://twitter.com/stevetdent): Developers can't use the Accessibility API for call recording starting May 11th.

Answer (score 1):

Recording global Audio in Android is now against Google's policy due to privacy concerns.

By default, audio recording from every app is locked, unless they actively set the RECORD_AUDIO permission.
By default, you can only record external audio through the microphone on Android.

Some references from **Android Developers**:

- [Sharing audio input](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/platform/sharing-audio-input)
- [Capture video and Audio Playback](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/platform/av-capture)

Comment: Any reference for this policy?