# Looking for a Flutter plugin that I can use to record device internal audio

Tags: flutter, dart, package, audio-recording, pub.dev

I have spent hours roaming pub.dev but no progress, I only see audio recording plugin that records audio my device microphone. Basically I want to be able to record a song playing on the device but recording this from microphone comes with alot of issues background noise etc.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76837348/how-to-record-internal-audio-in-a-flutter-app-on-android

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543466/how-to-record-internal-audio-on-android-devices-or-record-mediaplayer-audio-stre/60078178#60078178). It may be useful for you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

hey have u tried screen recorder packages coz they can record device video and internal audio (idk much but maybe it works with a little tweak)

Comment: I would check it out